# memory leak on shared delegate

Tags: url, memory-leaks, connection, warnings, shared

I am using shared delegate for getting data on URL connection. I'm getting a memory leak on my code. Can anybody please tell me what I have done wrong?

Analyser Warning:

> /Users/sathish/Documents/XXX 20100908 ManageMem/Classes/Data Download/XXX DataConnect.m:68:22: warning: Potential leak of an object allocated on line 68
>                    gXXXDataConnect = [[XXXDataConnect alloc] customInit] ;

XXXDataConnect.h

> - (XXXDataConnect*)sharedXXXDataConnect;

XXXDataConnect.m

> - (XXXDataConnect *)sharedXXXDataConnect
>     {
>     if(gXXXDataConnect == nil)
>     gXXXDataConnect = [[XXXDataConnect alloc] customInit] ;
>     return gXXXDataConnect ;
>     }

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're never deallocating your XXXDataConnect you've just allocated. If you don't deallocate it, who will?

Assuming this is Objective-C, I think you need a `return [gXXXDataConnect autorelease]` as your end-of-function. http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#retain might be a helpful link here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer kistaro but still that memory warning there even after putting return [gXXXDataConnect autorelease]